# Can Google Geocode returning addresses nearby

Tags: google-maps, ios, geocoding

I am using google geocoding to bring me addresses according to what a user type on the search box in my iOS app. I would like to know if it is possible, lets say when the user types m google api returns addresses that start with m in my state, country or even near my locality.

Is that possible to create a behaviour similar to the apple and google maps.

My url is this one:`@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&components=country:AU&sensor=true"`

Regards

Comment: Radar Search Requests by the Google Places API is what you require - API keys are required. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests

Comment: I will try it and come back with the results. Thank you

Comment: Notice: Google Places API Radar search is deprecated as of June 30, 2018. After that time, this feature will no longer be available.